# Backing up the database without compromising performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a data base with a size up to 120 Gb and I need do a backup every night.

The problem is that the system needs stand operative all the 24 hours.

In this moments the backup takes up to 2 hours to complete.

How I can do the backup without compromising server performance?

Thanks,
Andrés

Answer (score 9):

120GB should not take 2 hours

- Do you have a separate disk array for backups, with a separate network interface to move the backups off the server?
- If you have Enterprise Edition, can you use mirror backups
- Can you do weekly full backups and daily differentials?
- Is backup compression turned on (Standard in SQL Server 2008 R2+, Enterprise only in SQL Server 2008)

And without more details, it will be hard to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

Its very unlikely that your database changes by 120GB every day. Im not sure about the specifics with sql-server but one backup should taken every month or so, and then incremental backups in between. You may even be able to merge the backed up data with the incremental data as part of a script so the restore doesnt take the time running from 1 + (days since last whole backup) to update.

You could also replicate and take a backup of the replicated server which wouldnt effect the main server performance